# How do I Simplify a radical expressions

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

I'm having trouble understanding how to simplify the following radical expression.

$$\sqrt{3087}$$

Could someone please help me understand how to?

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of a radical expression you are having trouble with ?

Comment: the square root of 3087

Comment: Ok, so, are there any square number factors in $3087$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{3087}=\sqrt{3^2\cdot 7^3}=\sqrt{3^2}\cdot \sqrt{7^2}\cdot \sqrt{7}=3\cdot 7\cdot \sqrt{7}=21\sqrt{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

It' just $\sqrt{3087}=21\sqrt7$

Comment: A bit more informations could be helpful for the asker ...